# VB.NET: Two tiers for three layers or three tiers for three layers

Tags: design-patterns, vb.net

I asked a question on StackOverflow in November about separating a very large application into layers and tiers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342626/net-divorcing-layers.  The previous developer included data logic and business logic in the business logic layer

My question is about the tiers element.  I researched on here and concluded that it is better to separate layers into tiers contained in separate DLLs i.e. the presentation layer, business logic layer and data access layer all have separate DLLs as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342626/net-divorcing-layers.  This seems to be consistent with what I lEarnt at university.

However, since then all the examples I am finding online suggest having two tiers (One for the presentation layer and one tier for the BLL and DAL).

Is there any specific criteria that developers use to decide whether or not to use three tiers?

I am using ADO.NET and have a shared SQL Helper class in the data access layer.  The SQLHelper class is similar to this but for VB.NET: http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/source/SqlHelper-Source-Code-cs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any specific criteria that developers use to decide whether or not to use three tiers?

Whether or not the software layer must be capable of running on a separate machine.  That's the difference between a tier and a layer; a tier is a hardware abstraction.

> While the concepts of layer and tier are often used interchangeably, one fairly common point of view is that there is indeed a difference. This view holds that a layer is a logical structuring mechanism for the elements that make up the software solution, while a tier is a physical structuring mechanism for the system infrastructure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: Thanks. I have put the data access layer into a separate project. As a result of this a "shared" assembly is also needed. I could reduce the number of assemblies from four to two if I combine the bll and dal. As the DAL and BLL will run on the same machine, your answer suggests that they should be part of the same project and isolated using namespaces? +1.

Comment: My answer suggests that you don't need to make any special provisions for the bll and the dal to run on separate machines.  Whether you actually combine the two assemblies is not a decision that is affected by the hardware arrangement, in other words.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If the decision us not affected by hardware architecture, then what is it affected by?

Comment: Among other things, whether you need to separate out shared or common functionality into its own library assembly so that it can be used in a different application.

Comment: Thanks. I realise that sharing the code is one reason (I know i didn't specify this in the question). Could you clarify what you mean by: "among other things".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939457/when-to-separate-code-into-new-assemblies-dlls

Comment: That link was very useful. Thanks. Finally, as I stated in the question, the previous developer never created a data logic layer. I am refactoring as I go along but now there is inconsistency ie some code is refactored and some is not. Is it bad practice not to use an all or nothing approach? Ie refactor everything or nothing at all.

Comment: You're asking the wrong person whether something is bad practice or not. :)  There is no best way, there is only the way that best meets your requirements.  Do what makes sense.

Comment: +1 for simple clarification of a terminology misappropriation **many** people suffer from.